# SelectOutput block

Tags: select, output

I have a queue from which there are two delays I want to take items. I have put between the queue and the delays a SelectOutput block which I want to enforce an alternate distribution of the items in the queue to the two delays. In more details, when there are e.g. four items in the queue, one is directed (pulled) inside one of the delays, another (FIFO) to the other delay, when a delay finishes it pulls the third item, and when the other delay finishes (or the first, if it is faster) then it pulls in the last item.

I have tried to implement the above in two ways. Firstly, I have made the choice probabilistic (0.5). The other way that I used is to make the conditional choice that the first delay is chosen when the other is not empty.

However, in either way I observe that a number of items might be in the queue, a delay to be empty but not be chosen.

Why doesn't the delay block pull one of the items in?

Any ideas of how I can make the items to go to whichever delay is empty?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into it, and I think I found a way around. Here it goes:
Right after the queue that holds the items which are not pulled, place two blocks; one Delay with a very small (fixed) duration and a Hold block. These two blocks are also behind the SelectOutput block.
The Delay that was inserted pulls in an item, and the Hold block does not let proceed (i.e. has it waiting in a "push" state) until the conditions in it are met. The (holding) conditions are that both the Delays that follow have size() > 0 (Delay1.size() > 0 & Delay2.size() > 0) (Note: notice the single & in the condition. It makes sure that if the first condition is met then the second is also checked). This holds the item until a Delay of those that follow is empty, and when this is true, it lets the item proceed to the SelectOutput block. The SelectOutput block then directs the item according to the condition: Delay1.size() > 0.
Now, the Hold block condition needs to be re-evaluated whenever a relative change in its conditions are made. To stay in the safe side, I made the following checking in the On enter and the On exit actions of the Delay before the hold, and both the Delays that follow (hold.recalculateConditions();)